# Remove symbolic links only from a folder in tcsh

Tags: linux, tcsh, rm

I need to remove a large number of symbolic links from a folder that has other files which I don't want to remove.  Is there any easy way to remove only symbolic links?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) command

```
 find . -maxdepth 1 -type l -exec rm {} \;
```

- `-maxdepth 1` is for only scanning current directory.
- `-type l` is for searching symbolic links
- `-exec` executes `rm` to delete given file, the `{}` being replaced by `find` with an appropriate path, and the `\;` ending the sub-command run by `find`

See also the `man` page of [rm(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rm.1.html) (and of [ls(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html), [mv(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mv.1.html), [cp(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html), [ln(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ln.1.html), [stat(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) if you want to use them in a variant of that `find` command).

Comment: that looks neat.  Could you explain it?

Comment: I added a link to the documentation of `find`. Please take time to read it

Comment: @Simonare is there anyway to ensure I don't actually remove the folders which each link points to?

Comment: You can replace rm with ls

Comment: @Simonare I don't want to delete the files, only the soft link.  Moving the softlinks would also be an option -- would u be able to adapt this script to move the files instead?

Comment: @ZakS: Read again [find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html). And also [rm(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rm.1.html) and [mv(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mv.1.html). And *you* should be able to adapt the command

Comment: Rm only deletes symbolic link